# Что представляют собой фреймы L2 в модели OSI?

Tags: сеть, передача-данных

Разбирая концепцию взаимодействия сетевых устройств OSI, застрял на уровне 2 - канальном.

Не могу понять как работают MAC и LLC подуровни.
Сейчас я понимаю это так:

**При отправке**

1. LLC получает пакет от L3 и упаковывает его в LLC фрейм.
2. MAC упаковывает LLC фрейм в MAC фрейм
3. MAC обращается к PHY для отправки фрейма по сети

**При получении**

1. MAC получает от PHY фрейм
2. MAC проверяет MAC-адрес назначения в заголовке и отсеивает не интересные кадры
3. MAC вычисляет и проверяет CRC фрейма, отсеивая сломанные кадры
4. LLC извлекает из MAC фрейма LLC фрейм
5. LLC извлекает из LLC фрейма пакет и отправляет его нужному протоколу на L3

Правильно ли я понимаю алгоритм? Если нет, поправьте, возможно это будет ответом.

Если всё так, то какая задача у LLC фрейма?

Какой стандарт описывает структуру фреймов этого уровня? Я бы хотел что бы вы назвали стандарт, а я загуглил его и смог найти таблицу структур.

Если такого стандарта нет, значит ли это что каждый протокол может описывать структуру фреймов произвольно? Если это так, то получается что протоколы описывают устройство разных уровней OSI? Например протокол Ethernet описывает структуры фреймов L2 и какие кабели стоит использовать на уровне L1, а протокол VasyaPupkin228 описывает структуру пакетов уровня L3 и структуру фреймов L2?

Как работают сервисы LLC1, LLC2 и LLC3? Я имею в виду, что сервисы 2 и 3 требуют подтверждения приёма кадров и если кадр не битый, то он дойдет до уровня LLC и уровень сможет отправить управляющий кадр подтверждения приёма, но что если кадр битый? MAC уровень в таких случаях всегда шлет в ответ сообщение REJ, на адрес отправителя, а если адрес в фрейме не найден из-за сильного повреждения фрейма, то просто ничего не делает?

**p.s.** Прошу не требовать разбиения вопроса на отдельные, так как подвопросы атомарны, они об одном уровне модели OSI. На вопрос можно ответить одним сообщением по пунктам, можно даже в формате "да/нет", если подкреплять такие ответы ссылками.

Comment: MAC отвечает на вопрос "можно ли говорить", или сейчас кто-то общается, и следует молчать и ждать своей очереди (но можно подслушивать). LLC - если можно, то "кто с кем сейчас говорит", т.е. кому я говорю, либо мне ли говорят.

Comment: @Akina мой вопрос о том, как реализуют эти протоколы. Точнее что или даже посредством чего. Какова зона использования? Я бы задал наводящий вопрос, но не хочу, потому что это может сбить с толку других людей. Задам его если не получу ответа в ближайшее время. Потому что не знающим людям может показаться наводящий вопрос логичным и они (не зная так это на самом деле или нет) могут начать писать что всё так, хотя об этом нигде нет информации в гугле

Comment: *мой вопрос о том, как реализуют эти протоколы. Точнее что или даже посредством чего.* А вот это уже зависит от того, какая используется среда передачи. Везде по-своему.

Comment: @Akina  этого не может быть. L1 не могут же реализовать через ПО или например через аниме. Исключительно физически, через указанные выше методы. Получается сущности L1, это, например, провода. А сущности L7 - это пользовательские программы. Сущности L3, я подозреваю, это пакеты (ещё не дочитал, сначала хочу разобраться с L2). Что тогда сущности MAC & LLC?

Comment: Вероятно, биты, дешифрованные из уровней сигналов и их изменений, и их последовательности...

Comment: Да. Это называется фреймами в этой концепции. Но что реализует эти протоколы MAC & LLC? Как они управляют данными? L1 модуляторами отправляет сигналы, L7 посылает сигналы приложениями. L3 это наверное просто формат данных, а L2 описывает управление данными. При помощи чего MAC & LLC манипулируют данными?

Comment: Я надеюсь вы сможете прочитать на английском, просто переводить долго: примерная суть: http://computernetworkingsimplified.in/data-link-layer/components-data-link-layer-llc-mac/
Если вас интересует, что именно лежит за всем этим: то это ASIC, FPGA и еще всякие такие микросхемы. Для некоторых устройств, например, Mikrotik - просто софт операционной системы + драйвер сетевой карты.

Comment: MAC и LLC совсем не манипулирует данными, он манипулирует состоянием среды. И когда она свободна - отправляет фреймы (собранные в какой-то набор биты).

Comment: Ура! Вы сами сказали эти слова. Драйверы и чипы. Значит я не один так это понял. Я сейчас прочитаю, но прежде задам вопрос с чистым сознанием. А вы, если не знаете, укажите в ответе что это только ваша догадка, что бы не запутаться, а если не догадка - предоставьте ссылку доказывающую что это так. Я правильно понимаю что MAC представляет собой сетевую карту, а LLC драйвера к ней? И что задача преобразовать конечные данные (фреймы) в биты, для отправки по проводам (L1) делегируется MAC уровню?

Comment: @Axenow вопрос был адресован вам. Страницу прочитал, там прямо говорится "In end nodes and in intermediate devices like L2 switches and Routers, the LLC functionality is implemented in network device driver software that is part of the Operating System and the MAC functionality is implemented in dedicated piece of hardware.". Известны ли вам ещё источники утверждающие это? Я бы хотел ссылаться на эти страницы в будущем

Comment: @Петр Мне - нет, потому что я не запоминаю их. Мне достаточно уловить суть и знать как это работает.

Comment: @Петр Не правильно. Если сетевая карта глупая - всё делает драйвер, если умная - драйвер может не участвовать в процессе совсем. Есть так называемые low-latency network adapters - там вообще в FPGA вшит порт (сетевая карта), которая ничего не делает, кроме отправки сигнала.

Comment: @Axenow значит это абстрактные слои, обязанности которых не привязаны к конкретной реализации? Или даже самая глупая сетевая карта обязана выполнять некоторые задачи MAC подуровня? И правильно ли я понимаю, что "low-latency network adapters" это максимальный контроль для конечного пользователя, из-за того, что драйвер может выполнять абсолютно произвольную логику обработки данных (и самое дорогое, наверное, решение)?

Comment: 1. Не могу точно ответить про реализацию.
2. Да - даже самая глупая должна считать CRC и добавлять его в фрейм.
3. В точности до наоборот - это минимум контроля со стороны пользователя, но максимальная скорость работы. И да - стоят они как самолеты.

Comment: @Axenow а почему минимум контроля, если они аппаратно не реализуют никакой логики, а всё предлагают сделать драйверам, в которых может быть самая произвольная логика? И на счёт CRC, может тогда и отсеиванием кадров (поврежденных и с неправильным адресом) обязана заниматься карта? А может даже и разрешением коллизий в полудуплексных сетях?  (модераторов прошу не переносить это обсуждение в чат, пока мы обсуждаем вопросы по теме. Это важные уточнения)

Comment: Петр, мне кажется использовать SO для дискуссий - это не лучший вариант. Если вы хотите продолжить разговор, мне кажется это лучше сделать в личных сообщениях или любом мессанджере.

Comment: @Axenow не думаю что это дискуссия. Я не спорю с вами и это меня не интересует. Я только хочу понять зоны ответственности MAC & LLC. Не знаю есть ли на этом сайте сообщения, если да, то напишите мне, можем и там обсудить, а потом оформите это как ответ. Если ЛС нет и вы не хотите ответить на вопрос здесь, пожалуйста, не пишите больше ничего, просто подожду кого-нибудь другого, потому что каждое новое сообщение поднимает тему в модераторском интерфейсе, как тему с оффтопом, а если обсуждение переместят в чат, будет меньше шансов получить ответ из-за потери контекста обсуждения

Comment: Основная беда в том, что LLC и MAC - это не один стандарт. И дать только один единственный - вам не смогут. Даже в вики будет 5-6 протоколов LLC. В кратце: LLC - это логика L2 уровня(отвечает за то, чтобы данные были поняты), а MAC - это физика(отвечает за то, чтобы данные были переданы)

Comment: И да - это значит любой Вася может сделать свой стандарт LLC и MAC, который не будет поддерживаться никаким производителем и реализовать его только на своих устройствах. К слову говоря - много военного оборудования именно так и построены, чтобы стандартные средства перехвата не смогли перехватить данные.

Comment: @Axenow, да, уже сам начитался. Пришлось много гуглить. LLC отвечает за управление данными на канальном уровне, предоставляя сервисы. И судя по всему, именно LLC описывает только стандарт 802.2, а вот MAC - обязательная функциональность канального уровня. Если хотите, можете написать ответ, рассказав о том, что OSI абстрактная модель, описывающая разные задачи взаимодействия сетевых устройств в виде уровней и эти уровни различные протоколы могут реализовывать различно. Подкрепите ссылками и я прийму как ответ. Это могло бы помочь другим людям. Спасибо за ссылку выше.

Comment: Примите ответ, если он вас устраивает.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй суммировать, что я писал в комментариях, чтобы это выглядело как некоторый ответ.

1. OSI - это не конкретная модель, а абстрактная, которая позволяет немного упростить и ограничить круги решения проблем. Например, отсутствие ошибок на 4м и выше уровнях говорит о том, что проблемы надо искать в физики, канальном или сетевом уровне, что существенно ограничивает набор протоколов, которые необходимо исследовать и проверить.
2. Всё, что было отписано в описании вопроса в целом правильное. Исключением может быть только очень специфичные ситуации. Например, для устройств, которые занимаются высокочастотным трейдингом чаще всего LLC+MAC реализованы в одном чипе.
3. Хорошая ссылка с коротким описанием про LLC+МАС: http://computernetworkingsimplified.in/data-link-layer/components-data-link-layer-llc-mac/ Там вы можете прочитать в целом, зачем нужен LLC+MAC
4. Основная беда в том, что LLC и MAC - это не один стандарт. И дать только один единственный - вам не смогут. Даже в вики будет 5-6 протоколов LLC. В кратце: LLC - это логика L2 уровня(отвечает за то, чтобы данные были поняты), а MAC - это физика(отвечает за то, чтобы данные были переданы). Так же это значит, что любой может сделать свой стандарт LLC и MAC, который не будет поддерживаться никаким производителем и реализовать его только на своих устройствах.
5. На самом деле, если хочется уйти сильно глубже, то просто стоит поискать стандарты IEEE 802.2 - это самый распространенный LLC и 802.3 - это самый распространенный MAC. Даже открыв wiki на эти стандарты вы можете увидеть, как их много.